# I improved Maxwell's demon and think that I have broken the Second Law of Thermodynamics!

Tags: thermodynamics

My version of Maxwell's demon looks like this: **uninsulated** gas filled container is divided by a wall into A and B chambers. This wall contains **one way doors, all of their opening directions are pointed from A to B chamber**. door opens only in its opening direction when one (or more) gas molecule hits it from A chamber. Opening and closing processes require some portion of molecule's kinetic energy to be transferred to the door, but that is irrelevant. after some time, number of gas molecules will increase in B chamber and decrease in A chamber, creating pressure difference (container is not insulated) and decreasing entropy without energy input. I am not a physicist, so I want your review of my thought experiment. Did I break the second law?

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: "opening and closing processes require some portion of molecule's kinetic energy to be transferred to the door, but that is irrelevant" What is your argument for why this is irrelevant? I think it should be very relevant.

Comment: "The law that entropy always increases holds, I think, the supreme position among the laws of Nature. If someone points out to you that your pet theory of the universe is in disagreement with Maxwell's equations—then so much the worse for Maxwell's equations. If it is found to be contradicted by observation—well, these experimentalists do bungle things sometimes. But if your theory is found to be against the Second Law of Thermodynamics I can give you no hope; there is nothing for it to collapse in deepest humiliation." A. Eddington

Comment: The Eddington quote being said, welcome to Physics! [In this site, we deal with mainstream physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/168783), meaning that speculative questions that try to put in check established knowledge will almost always be [closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question will be better welcomed if you rephrase it in a manner that shows your doubts without suggesting established knowledge to be wrong.

Comment: For example, instead of asking whether you have broken the second law (which you surely didn't), the question might be better suited to this website if you ask what is it that you are missing and leading to the appearance that the second law is being violated.

Comment: macrosopically, kinetic energy is transferred to the right,(including the one left on the door), temperature will rise on the right and fall on the lerft,  from PV=NkT, there will be a rise in pressure, which will no longer be equal in the two chambers, and the door will remain closed.

Comment: Also macroscopically if the pressure is the same in the two chambers in the beginning the door will remain closed, of course, no matter how thin and sensitive, as the impact even of  a high energy molecule will not be enough to counteract the pressure from the side of chamber 2.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_ratchet

You basically reinvented this, with some minor changes.

This type of devices work if there is a sufficient temperature difference. If not, then motion will be equal in both direction for your door.

It is experimentally tested with Brownian motion that consist of many particles.

You may say that your case is unique, that you expect a single particle hit. Then consider that your door needs to be much lighter than a particle so that your particle doesn't just bounce off  when it hits the door. But this door will be more often hit from the other side. Either bending from hits and making incoming particle impulse not enough, or bouncing back, and letting the gas in reverse direction. Or if there is some sort of smart impulse control, wasting energy on it.

Comment: i think that illustrations make it clear that door is rigid. only chance it could let molecules from b side is that door is opened due to hitting from b direction (door bounces off) or a direction and letting other nearby molecule in b chamber to pass through. but there is obviously much lower probability of that happening than just one molecule hitting. I never said this method is flawless, but it will reach reasonable equilibrium as I see it.

Comment: thank you for reviewing my idea, i greatly appreciate it.

Comment: i think idea of Brownian ratchet is rater easy to defy, as it asks work to be done by single molecules (quite far fetched if you ask me). my idea is rather different, as it causes macro changes - pressure, concentration, by many micro actions: molecule passing or not.