# I invite you to debunk my version of Maxwell's demon. turns out it is called Smoluchowski's Trapdoor

Tags: thermodynamics

My version of Maxwell's demon looks like this: an uninsulated, gas-filled container is divided by a wall into A and B chambers. This wall contains one-way doors; all of their opening directions are pointed from A to B chamber.  After some time, the number of gas molecules will increase in the B chamber and decrease in the A chamber, creating pressure difference (container is not insulated) and decreasing entropy without energy input.

[image] [image] [image]

IMPORTANT NOTES:
This is not a Maxwell's demon (it doesn't require any measurements or storage for measurement).
This is not a Brownian Ratchet (it doesn't extract usable energy from individual molecules during the micro-processes and doesn't have an overcomplicated mechanism, begging to be criticized). Please do not compare my system to Brownian ratchet and if you do, provide solid arguments.

I am not a physicist, which is why I am trying to refine my idea here with your constructive criticism. I know many great physicists said breaking the second law is impossible, so just relax and help me solve this "paradox" I created. If you are interested, see specifics below. I did not want to specify this much, but people tend to make assumptions that I never made and conclude that my idea is flawed because of their own assumptions.

Specifics of the door: has a significantly lower mass than gas particles; is rigid and almost does not bend; returns to its shut position via spring. Spring shuts the door relatively quickly after particle leaves. Passing through the door requires a portion of the kinetic energy of the particle to be transferred into the door. Door dissipates this energy into the wall.  Walls are not insulated and thus are always at ambient temperature. because of the same reason, passed particle regains its lost energy. The door can be also opened to some (probably small) extent by collision from the B side due to backlash. The door is vibrating due to heat but doesn't open significantly because the spring holds it. The spring can hold the door but not a particle because as we said particle is much heavier.

Gas specifications: gas has small enough concentration that in the door's reach there is approximately one molecule.

Leaking specifications: particles from the B side can leak into the A-side if the door is opened due to the aforementioned reasons, which include opening the door mainly by A particle, with lower extent by B particle and with much lower extent by a random increase in its kinetic energy. For first and second situations to happen, the door must be hit almost simultaneously with two or more particles, one of which is on the B side. probability of that happening is much lower than the probability of just one particle hitting the door from A side, which will be true until a concentration of particles on the B side increases significantly and equilibrium is reached (remember gas specifications).
[image]

After all these specifications, I am eager to know what flaws you might find.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693842/2451

Comment: I personally find the description a bit confusing: can you state the properties of the system (in particular, of the door) that we have to consider in a few clear and short points at the beginning?

Comment: in my opinion the basic flaw is in your idea of gas. If one only molecule can move the door, with no other around, that is called vacuum  with a few molecules. In addition the door has to be made of molecules so it cannot be lighter in weight than any molecule. It is a science fiction scenario.

Comment: @annav thank you for feedback. isn't it fun how integrity of second law has boiled down to engineering problems? can't i make concentration of gas so low, that in specific amount of volume distribution of particles peaks at 1 molecule or less on average?. can't gas molecules be big end energetic enough to open the door which might contain small amount of gold atoms?

Comment: The second law  is classical thermodynamics. single molecules are quantum physics and  connected with thermodynamics when in *great numbers* by statistical mechanics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics#Statistical_thermodynamics

Answer (score 6):

This is called *Smoluchowski's Trapdoor* and has been studied since it was first published in 1912. A good resource is from John D Norton's page on [*The Simplest Exorcism of Maxwell's Demon*](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/Goodies/exorcism_phase_vol/exorcism_phase_vol.html) in which he describes that it cannot work as intended because of the following rationale (under the heading "An Illustration: The Smoluchowski Trapdoor"),

> Smoluchowski pointed out that the trapdoor must itself be very light and very lightly spring loaded if a collision with one air molecule is to open it. As a result it has its own random motion due to thermal fluctuations and is, of its own accord, flapping about in a way that is uncoordinated with the motion of the molecules in the air. Thus, it lets air molecules pass freely in both directions and no accumulation of air on one side can happen.
>
> [image]

The original paper by Smoluchowski can [be found here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015023176806&view=1up&seq=1159&q1=smoluchowski), though it is in German and contains no images.

For a more modern treatment, one can look at [Zheng et al (2007)](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.75.041109) that performs a molecular dynamics simulation of the system and finds,

> ...no visible temperature differentiation has been achieved by the trapdoor for the duration of the simulation. This reflects the fact that being hit frequently by the incoming particles the Maxwell demon is heated up, reaching thermal equilibrium with the gaseous particles, and loses therefore its designated functionality. This was pointed out precisely by Smoluchowski one century ago. The particle-door system is in thermal equilibrium and any temperature differentiation is in fact prohibited by the second law of thermodynamics.

Essentially they found that the probability of transition from colder side to hotter side was equal to the probability of transition from hotter to colder,
$$ P\left(\dot\theta,\,v_i\right)=P\left(-\dot\theta,\,-v_i\right)$$
where $\dot\theta$ is the trap door's angular velocity and $_i$ the velocity of the $i$th particle, which is due to the [principle of microscopic reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microscopic_reversibility)

Comment: thank you for providing that resource, but counterargument is not rigorous. why can't i say that at given temperature door has certain average amplitude of moving, moreover why can't i say say that that amplitude is small enough to make statistics work in my favor?

Comment: @nikopapiashvili because it is temperature you are talking about. If door flaps less, it must be colder. If door flaps about as much as particles move about, it is similar in temperature.

Comment: @nikopapiashvili Norton's treatment was simplifying it on purpose, but rigorous treatments exist. I have included an additional remark on a modern treatment (wherein they even performed a simulation of the system and found Smoluchowski's argument correct).

Comment: as we said the door is very light, thus it can't gain much impulse from colliding to the wall, thus door will have much smaller kinetic energy than particle. this allows us to use spring with high K, which still allows particles to pass through, but doesn't the let door to flap around. is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @niko If the door is in thermal equilibrium with the gas, it has the same kinetic energy as the mean kinetic energy of the gas. So if the door is supposed to be lighter than the gas molecules then you expect the door vibration speed to be higher than the gas molecule speed.

Comment: @nikopapiashvili Once a collision occurs, the trap door is **open**. With it being open, there is nothing stopping particles from the "hot" side leaking *back* into the "cold" side. Ergo, the probability of transition between the two sides are identical and no temperature increase would be observed.

Comment: we don't care about door vibration speed, we care about door vibration amplitude.

Comment: even if speed is high, due to low mass, door will have low amplitude.

Comment: Even if you want to assume that $\theta_\text{max}$ is small, the probability of moving from cold to hot is still the same as the probability of moving the other way (it's just smaller than if $\theta_\text{max}=\pi$). You cannot prevent that from happening, which is the whole resolution to the Smoluchowski trapdoor scenario.

Comment: i stated condition, that there is only one molecule in door's close proximity.

Comment: @nikopapiashvili The particle distribution would be uniform in each chamber, so you couldn't enforce that unphysical condition.

Comment: @KyleKanos i can say that particle concentration is so low, that in small area (in our case area around door) there is more chance of one particle being than more.

Comment: @nikopapiashvili I am getting the feeling that you are not going to accept any criticisms of the model as valid by adding whatever (unphysical) conditions you want to make it violate laws of thermodynamics. Have fun with that.

Comment: i didn't add anything, i have already stated in main body that in amount of volume that fits my needs, particle distribution peaks at one particle or less. am I saying something extraordinary?

Comment: i am accepting and am very thankful for your criticism. i am just presenting counterarguments.

Comment: i might have understood why you said "whatever (unphysical) conditions ". i didn't say that concentration must be 1 or less near door and different in other parts of container, but you may have thought i did.

Answer (score 4):

The important question you need to ask is: What temperature is the spring? Is it vibrating?

Say a gas molecule goes from the left box to the right box at speed, it knocks the door open, goes through, and leaves the door shaking on its spring. The spring is shaking, the door rattling open and closed. When it is open molecules might get through in the wrong direction.

Ok, but you might argue that the door will settle down and stop rattling. How? Well to stop rattling around the door needs to loose its energy (heat) into something else. It might hit a gas molecule and kick it of at high speed (slowing the door down) for example. What your proposed machine is doing is exploiting the fact that the gas is at a higher temperature than the door-spring mechanism to extract useful work. As the door-spring system comes into thermal equilibrium with the gas the machine will stop producing power.

You could provide a cooling system for the spring-door system. That could keep your machine running, but of course at that point it is a heat-engine extracting work from the temperature difference between your gas and the cold bath that cools the spring down.

This is exactly what you do: "Door dissipates this energy into the wall. Walls are not insulated and thus are always at ambient temperature." - If this is the case the door is the same temperature as the particles, and the machine will not do work.

For some insight into the problem, you can think of your door shaking around after it takes a "hit" as being equivalent to the memory in the memory version of the demon. When you re-set the door (cool it, so it stops shaking) you are doing something equivalent to replacing the demons memory.

Comment: door has two states: closed - low energy (note that it is touching walls which have same temperature as gas, and i have stated that in that state even though door is vibrating, it doesn't open that much) and open - high energy, which will decay into low energy state. isn't that correct? now it is just a matter of how fast that decay will happen. in other words, i am letting system to clear it's own memory.

Comment: @nikopapiashvili. No, a high-energy state does not automatically decay into a low energy one. Energy is conserved, in order for the high energy state to evolve into the low energy one that energy has to go into something else. Physics is reversible, this means that if the door can loose energy into some other thing (called a bath), then energy from that bath can cross over into the door. The door will find a state that puts it at the same temperature as its bath. If the bath is cold your machine works, but while working it heats the bath up. Its a heat engine.

Comment: as i said system is not insulated, thus bath is whole world. when door goes into high energy state it will loose that energy to walls due to excessive vibration.

Comment: You can make use of black-body radiation, but then you're still using a heat differential to do work. each time the door swings open, dumps its heat into a radiator and the radiator emits a bunch of photons, the energy spent to do the process is now lost to the gas. Once the gas cools down enough to match the radiation background (2 kelvin for our universe, give or take), the radiator stops cooling the door and the door will swing open and shut randomly and stops pumping. Also note that at low temperatures, radiative cooling _quickly_ slows down.

Comment: there is no need for radiator. as i said said walls are the ''bath" so they will take excessive energy themselves, wont they?